# Webpack Post CSS Plugin not adding vendor prefix

Tags: javascript, webpack, autoprefixer, postcss

I am trying to use the wepback loader and plugin for PostCSS autoprefixer. All the SCSS is compiling but not getting prefixed.

This is what I have in my config:

```
loaders: {
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader!autoprefixer-loader"
    },
    {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
             'style',
             'css?sourceMap!sass?sourceMap'
         )
    },
}
postcss: autoprefixer({
        browsers: [
            'last 2 versions',
            'ie >= 9'
        ]
    })
```

What am I missing.

There are places where I have used flexbox and they aren't getting prefixed

Comment: the `postcss` key needs to be in the root config not in `module` where `loaders` is